# How did "en fragante" happen?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, rae

From the Latin we have:

[in flagrante delicto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_flagrante_delicto)

> "caught in the act"

...in English, but we use the term in a legal sense as is.

In Spanish, we have [**en flagrante**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I2Ypxbe),

> 1. loc. adv. En el mismo momento de estarse cometiendo un delito, sin que el autor haya podido huir.

but I often notice the local newspapers, such as *La Prensa Libre*, use [***en fragante***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IMShyOq%7CIMU5Elt) for the same purpose. I checked in DRAE, and definition 2 gives them as being used interchangeably.

> 1. loc. adv. en flagrante.

How did this happen, as the usual definition of *fragante* has to do with scent?

Comment: Interesting link: http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/In%20fraganti%20-%20in%20flagranti.htm , where you can read: "La expresión latina *in flagranti* se deformó en la expresión española *in fraganti*, quizás por contaminación con *fragante* ‘oloroso’, del participio latino *fragrans, fragrantis* del verbo *fragrare* ‘echar olor’."

Comment: @Yay It is interesting, but it says _quizás_, so they are not really sure how or why?

Comment: Indeed, that's why I don't post it as an answer. I personally think it is a plausible explanation but without further evidence it is little more than speculation.

Comment: Another interesting link: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Met%C3%A1tesis It's also [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)) but the Spanish page is funnier.

Comment: Here is the same idea but at least it comes from a published book: https://books.google.es/books?id=RxGv6tMX2QcC&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=fragante+flagrante&source=bl&ots=DU_pMFtOCg&sig=z9Ljw6Osm1cTOrVoZn14UsDppO4&hl=es&sa=X&ei=3llYUb7ZOMTJPZe9gNgI#v=onepage&q=fragante%20flagrante&f=false

Comment: @Yay I had found that book ref. in the meantime; I am wondering if the issue has to do with the pronunciation of the "L" following an "F", like here some people have problems with TL, as in Atlantic.

Comment: @Yay I think the definition of _metátesis_ actually explains it, or at least makes a good attempt. I had wondered about _cocodril_, also.

Comment: I don't know much about phonology, but *I'd say* /fl/ is just an unstable cluster. /fl/ isn't particularly hard to pronounce for Spanish speakers (think of "flor", "flecha" or "flotar"), but it definitely doesn't roll off the tongue as well as /fr/ does.

Comment: I think the metathesis is quite clear in this case, and the influence of the preexisting word *fragante* is clear too. An ethymology cannot always be traced with absolute certainty, hence the *quizás* in @Yay's link, but I can't really see an alternative explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*En fragante* or *in fraganti* is, as evidenced in many sources, a distorted form of the Latin expression *in flagranti*:

> [**in fraganti**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LYnESFR)
>   Tb. **infraganti.**
>   Del lat. *in flagranti [crimĭne]* 'en flagrante [delito]'.

The expression *fraganti* came about through a process of metathesis by which the /r/ moved to the place where the /l/ used to be, and the latter was dropped. There is a possibility the Latin word *fragante* also promoted such a change, as proposed by Fernando Díez Losada in the journal column [*La tribuna del idioma*](https://books.google.es/books?id=RxGv6tMX2QcC&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=fragante+flagrante&source=bl&ots=DU_pMFtOCg&sig=z9Ljw6Osm1cTOrVoZn14UsDppO4&hl=es&sa=X&ei=3llYUb7ZOMTJPZe9gNgI#v=onepage&q=fragante%20flagrante&f=false):

> La expresión latina auténtica es **in flagranti** (*in flagranti crimine/delicto*), que en el siglo XVII se castellanizó en la forma **en flagrante** (con frecuencia acompañada del sustantivo **delito**). Posteriormente se dio un fenómeno que podríamos considerar de asimilación consonántica: **flagrante** se convirtió, en labios del pueblo, en **fragante** (tal vez, incluso, por influencia del adjetivo **fragante**: oloroso, aromático). Con ello se consideraron correctas y se alternaron las dos expresiones: **en flagrante** y **en fragante**.

The distorted form certainly isn't new, dating back to at least 1505:

> El marido que matare por su propia autoridad al adultero & ala adultera avn que los tome **infraganti** delito y sea justamente fecha la muerte no gane la dote ni los bienes del que matare (...).
>   Anónimo (1505). *Leyes de Toro. Real Chancillería Valladolid. Pergaminos*

The cluster /fl/ was kept in other forms derived from the same root such as *inflamar* or *flamígero*, but it also evolved to a /ʎ/ and eventually a /ʝ/ in most dialects, giving us the cognate doublets *flama* and *llama* or *flamear* and *llamear*.

So to answer your question, to what extent the Latin word *fragante* affected the evolution of *flagrante* isn't easy to tell, but it is a plausible explanation. After all, two words don't have to be semantically related to influence each other; if that were the case, [malapropisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) wouldn't exist.