# Origen de "in fraganti"

Tags: etimología, adverbios, locuciones

Ya sabemos que en el DLE nunca se ha incorporado la voz [*cocreta*](https://dle.rae.es/cocreta), por mucho que algunos se empeñen en decir que sí. Sin embargo, algunas corrupciones similares sí que han llegado al diccionario, como la que hoy destaca la RAE como palabra del día:

> [**in fraganti**](https://dle.rae.es/in%20fraganti)
>
> Tb. **infraganti**.
>
> Del lat. *in flagranti [crimĭne]* 'en flagrante [delito]'.
>
> 1. loc. adv. En el mismo momento en que se está cometiendo el delito o realizando una acción censurable.

Si nos fijamos, una corrupción similar sucede en el cambio de *flagranti* a *fraganti*. La locución [*en flagrante*](https://dle.rae.es/flagrante) también se recoge en el DLE (y en el del [español jurídico](https://dpej.rae.es/lema/flagrante)) con una definición similar.

Mi pregunta es: ¿en qué momento se creó la forma corrupta *in fraganti*? ¿Desde cuándo existen registros escritos de esta locución? ¿Es relativamente reciente o la corrupción viene ya de antiguo?

Comment: Mmmm parece que ya se respondió en [How did “en fragante” happen?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17530/1674), respuesta de Yay

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' pues ya está esta apuntando a la otra, ¡gracias!